# Call function in jquery from angular controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, scope

I am attempting to build an edit in place function with Angular and jQuery.
It is the jQuery that does the DOM manipulation and Angular does the data.

My quertion is how do I call the jQuery function resetString() from inside $scope.updateString?

You can see the code in action here:

https://pigfox.com/angular

I have the following view:

```
    <div data-ng-app="Demo" data-ng-controller="cntrl">
            <div><input type="text" name="string" data-ng-model="string" class="form-control w300" placeholder="Enter string"/></div>
            <div><input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="insert();"/></div>
            <div>{{msg}}</div>
            <table id="strings">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th colspan="4">String<span class="small">(click to edit)</span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="row in data track by $index">
                        <td>{{row.id}}</td>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <td class="w100 string" id="string-{{row.id}}">{{row.string}}</td>
                        <td><button data-ng-click="deleteString(row.id);" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button></td>
                        <td><button data-ng-click="updateString(row.id);" class="btn btn-primary save" id="save{{row.id}}">Save</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary reset_string" id="reset_string{{row.id}}">Reset</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Here's my Angular app.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('Demo',[]);

app.controller('cntrl', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.insert = function(){
        $http.post('/angular/insert', {string:$scope.string})
        .success(function(){
            $scope.msg="Data inserted";
            $scope.displayString();
        })
    }

    $scope.displayString = function(){
        $http.get('/angular/all')
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.data = data
        })
    }

    $scope.deleteString = function(id){
        $http.post('/angular/delete', {'id':id})
        .success(function(){
            $scope.msg = "Data Deleted";
            $scope.displayString();
        })
    }

    $scope.updateString = function(id){
        $scope.newstring = $('#newstring').val();
        $http.post('/angular/update', {'id':id, 'string':$scope.newstring})
        .success(function(){
            $scope.msg = "Data Updated";
            $scope.displayString();
            resetString();
        })
    }

    $scope.displayString();

});
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var string = '';
var raw_id = '';

$(document).on('click', '.string', function () {
    if ($(this).attr('name') == 'newstring')
        return false;

    string = $(this).html();
    raw_id = this.id;
    var td_id = this.id.split('-');
    var save = '#save' + td_id[1];
    $(save).show();
    var close = '#reset_string' + td_id[1];
    $(close).show();
    var input = '<input class="form-control w100 string" value="' + string + '" type="text" data-ng-model="newstring" name="newstring" id="newstring"/>';
    $(this).html(input);
});

$(document).on('click', '.reset_string', function () {
    resetString(); 
});

function resetString(){
    //reset <td>
    var string_id_td = '#' + raw_id;
    $(string_id_td).html(string);

    //get the numerical id
    var td_id = raw_id.split('-');

    //hide  reset button
    var reset_string = '#reset_string' + td_id[1];      
    $(reset_string).hide();

    //hide save button
    var save = '#save' + td_id[1];
    $(save).hide();  
}
```

});

Comment: Why use jquery?  This could, and arguably should, all be done in angular with a single collection and ng-repeat.

Comment: I was told never to mix JQuery with Angular.  You start getting side effects like this pretty quickly.  I've heard Knockout is much more compatible and can accomplish the same things as Angular however.  If you have the option at this point, maybe look into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not advisable to mix jQuery and AngularJS. But if you want to do you can assign `resetString` to some global scope for example

```
window.myFunctions = {resetString: resetString}; // in jQuery
```

and inside AngularJS you can invoke resetString by

```
window.myFunctions.resetString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your resetString() out of $(document).ready to give a global scope.

```
function resetString() {
  // to do resetting string code here
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   // you can call resetString() from here;
});
```

Now you can access resetString() from your angular controller also -

```
app.controller('cntrl', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.updateString = function(id){
        resetString();    
    }
});
```